# Http redirect for all except one page

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect

Can anybody advice how to redirect everything from https://{url}/$1 apart from https://{url}/content to {url2}/$1

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} yourfirstdomain.com
RewriteRule ^(?!content)(.*) https://yourseconddomain.com/$1 [NE,L,R]
```